# TypeError 'Cannot read property/undefined ' when using toString property

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to code a basic calculator, and I ran into a wall.  I am trying to display multiple numbers on the output, I did declare currentOperand as an empty variable in the clear(). In the appendNumber() if I set the this.currentOperand equal to number it will display but only single digit. It was advise to return a string value in the this.currentOperand to output multiple numbers.

JS Code

```
    constructor(previousoperandTextElement, currentoperandTextElement){
        this.previousoperandTextElement = previousoperandTextElement
        this.currentoperandTextElement = currentoperandTextElement
    }
    clear(){
        this.currentOperand = "";
        this.previousOperand = "";
        this.operation = undefined; 
    }
    
    delete(){

    }
    appendNumber(number){
        if(number === "." && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
        console.log(number);
    }
    chooseOperation(operation){

    }
    compute(){

    }
    updateDisplay(){
        this.currentoperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
    }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]")
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]")
const deleteButton = document.querySelector("[data-delete]")
const all_clearButton = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]")
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("[data-equals]")
const previousoperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-previous-operand]")
const currentoperandTextElement = document.querySelector("[data-current-operand]")

const calculator = new Calculator(previousoperandTextElement, currentoperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
        calculator.updateDisplay();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the current operand not a string already? So you wouldn't need to convert it to a string.

So

```
this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand + number.toString()
```

You can also check the type first in console before converting to strings just to be sure of what you're trying to convert:

```
console.log(typeof this.currentOperand);
```

If you use Typescript, these sort of things would be much clearer too.

**Edit** on looking back over it it also looks like the variable `number` is a string. If it's going to be strictly equal to "." - you are trying to convert a string which contains `.` into a string, which it already is.